# How save activity with custom markers added?

Tags: android, google-maps

In my app i have a map so when users taps on the map at a point they can add custom markers.  Now the problem is when I have added a few markers and leave the app all the markers are gone.  I need to save those markers so that when the app starts again or user navigates away from the map and returning, their markers should then still be there.

Here is my activity:

```
public class Test extends Activity implements OnMapLongClickListener,  OnMapClickListener, OnMarkerClickListener{


private GoogleMap googleMap;
static final LatLng Point1 = new LatLng(xx.xxx, xx.xxx);
static final LatLng Point2 = new LatLng(xx.xxx, xx.xxx);
static final LatLng Point3 = new LatLng(xx.xxx, xx.xxx);
static final LatLng Point4 = new LatLng(xx.xxx, xx.xxx);

Bitmap bitmap;
private static final int TAKE_PICTURE = 0;
private static Uri fileUri;
final Context context = this;


@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_googlemaps);
}

@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

  try {
        initilizeMap();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }


private void initilizeMap() {
    if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
    public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    initilizeMap();

    if (googleMap!=null){
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Point1)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker)));
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Point2)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker)));
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Point3)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker)));
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Point4)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker)));
          }

 CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(
         new LatLng(xx.xxx, xx.xxx)).zoom(9).bearing(0).tilt(80).build();

 googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
 googleMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
 googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
 googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
 googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
 googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
 googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
 googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
 googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
 }


public void onMapLongClick(final LatLng point) {

      Intent getCameraImage = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
         getApplicationContext().getDir(
                 getResources().getString(R.string.app_name), MODE_PRIVATE);

         fileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File((Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
                 "/" +getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)),new Date().getTime() + ".jpg"));

            getCameraImage.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

         startActivityForResult(getCameraImage, TAKE_PICTURE);

        }    

  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

              try {
                  GetImageThumbnail getImageThumbnail = new GetImageThumbnail();
                  bitmap = getImageThumbnail.getThumbnail(fileUri, this);
              } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                  e1.printStackTrace();
              } catch (IOException e1) {
                  e1.printStackTrace();
              }
              {


              MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
             .position(Position)
             .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
             .fromBitmap(bitmap));
             googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            }
        }
 }

        public void onMapClick (LatLng point){
    }

        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    context)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_dialog);

                // set title
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("My Marker");

                // set dialog message
                alertDialogBuilder
                    .setMessage("Select Option")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Display full Image",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                             Intent intent = new Intent();
                                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                Uri imgUri = Uri.parse("file://" + fileUri);
                                intent.setDataAndType(imgUri, "image/*");
                                startActivity(intent);
                        }
                      })

                    .setNegativeButton("Delete Marker",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                            // if this button is clicked, just close
                            marker.remove();
                        }
                    });

                    // create alert dialog
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                    // show it
                    alertDialog.show();
                    return false;
                }

        }
```

Hope some one can help
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Google maps doesn't keep the marker for you. You should save the positions on your database and re-load the information at start-up (in your `onCreate()` and better in async way).

OT: you are using deprecated API, the `getMap()` has been replaced with `getMapAsync()`

Comment: Thanks,  have you got an example for me to follow?

Comment: Try to look at the SQLite example in android doc. You just need to save a couple of information and add it again with addMarker() maybe using an AsyncTask, nothing more.